# Move Category Layered Navigation to bottom of sidebar Magento

Tags: html, xml, magento, block

**Magento 1.9 rwd theme**
I cannot get the Category Layered Navigation to move. I can remove it but I don't want to remove it. I just want to move it. cannot get it to respond to either "unsetChild" or before/after. I have tried every suggestion I can find and nothing will work. What I really want is the "regular" category navigation in the left block with the layered navigation below it but the layered navigation will not budge. This is what I have now:

```html
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.categories" before="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
            <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
        </reference>
 </catalog_category_layered>
```

I have tried a variety of combinations on the layered navigation. In my catalog.xml I have changed the placing to after="-". I have changed the compare sidebar to before. I have tried many combinations of the below code in my local.xml

```html
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>catalog.leftnav</alias></action>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
    <action method="insert"><blockName>catalog.leftnav</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The reference name needs to be

```html
<reference name="left_first">
```

instead of just

```html
<reference name="left">
```

The code is as follows

```html
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.categories" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
 <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
        <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```